# Which steps should I follow to determine the level of a glass of any liquid?

Tags: java, opencv

I'm fairly new to OpenCV Java and I've been looking for methods to do what the title asks.
So far, from what I understood, the first step should be to use a detecting edges filter like Sobel or Laplace.

Coming from https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/d2c/tutorial_sobel_derivatives.html, I get the following result : [glass_sobel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIdKZ.png)

From now on, I don't know what to do next... What should I do to get what I want ?
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the vertical edge difference (sobel) is indeed the right step. But first I suggest fixing some parameters. For instance, is the position, size and shape of the glass fixed? then take an image without fluid and use that to extrapolate the glass from the result. If not, I would take the following steps:
Try to increase edge visibility. In your image you do see a clear edge, but the computer might see this as 4 edges, therefore try to make sure edges close to each other are seen as one edge (dilate operation might do that). Depending on the liquid, you could alternatively extract a certain color from the image. Water is here the most unfortunate case, but something as orange juice is easily detected.
With the more clear edges, I would try to get a vertical line out of the glass, and classify each edge (is it part of glass or part of liquid).